# Slicing a list item that exists in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, geopy

I have a list (named split_dfs) that contains several dataframes with 100 rows in each. These dataframes each contain columns with coordinate data that is stored in lists. i.e there is a column named Destination Coordinates and every row has data such as [41.67907634659514, -73.88281655538246, 0.0]. They look as follows:

[image]

I am attempting to compute the mile difference between the two coordinate columns, but as evident, one of the coordinate columns has 3 points(the 0 is for altitude) which causes an error in the computation. To reiterate, each row in the coordinate columns contains a list.

How can I loop through every dataframe in the list and slice the Destination Coordinate column to get rid of the 3rd point and keep only the first 2 in each row. I have tried the following:

```
for i in split_dfs:
    for x in i["Destination Coordinates"]:
        x=x[:2]
```

This returns 'NoneType object is not subscriptable'. The transformation I am trying to perform works if I do it in a list comprehension for every dataframe individually i.e:

```
first_group["Destination Coordinates"]=[i[:2] for i in first_group["Destination Coordinates"]]
```

I would like to be able to do this in a loop rather than write code for every dataframe individually.

Thank you.

Comment: Read again the first 2 paragraphs of your question. It is quite hard to conceptualize all that without a clear example. You should provide that.

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of the input dataframe in code form? (not a screenshot)

Comment: If you gave the data as copyable text instead of as an image we could try to reproduce...

Comment: @ChrisSears what do you mean by rows of the input dataframe? I apologize for not understanding I am a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an element of a dataframe that way.

What you want is probably:

```
for i in split_dfs:
    i['Destination Coordinates'] = i['Destination Coordinates'].transform(
        lambda x: x[:2] if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```